# API login issues

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I created API and trying to login user. While 127.0.0.1:8000/api/register works perfectly find but authentication in /api/login error is getting. In settings.py

I set `auth_user_model = 'account.AppUser'`

Still I am getting this error:

> POST /api/login/
> HTTP 400 Bad Request
> Allow: POST, OPTIONS
> Content-Type: application/json
> Vary: Accept

```json
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "User not found"
    ]
}
```

```py
#account/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from django.db import models

JOB_TYPE = (
    ('M', "Male"),
    ('F', "Female"),

)

ROLE = (
    ('employer', "Employer"),
    ('employee', "Employee"),
)

'''class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': "A user with that email already exists.",
                              })
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE,  max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=1)


    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name+ ' ' + self.last_name
    objects = CustomUserManager()
 '''

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('The Password must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
     if not email:
        raise ValueError('An email is required.')
     if not password:
        raise ValueError('A password is required.')
     user = self.create_user(email, password)
     user.is_superuser = True
     user.save()
     return user     


class AppUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        #user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
        objects = CustomUserManager()
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.username
```

```
#account/serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate
#from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

UserModel = get_user_model()

class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

    def create_user(self, clean_data):
        user_obj = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            email=clean_data['email'], 
            password=clean_data['password'])
        user_obj.username = clean_data['username']
        user_obj.save()

        return user_obj        

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    ''' def check_user(self, data):
        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            email=data['email'],
            password=data['password']
        )   '''

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'), email=email, password=password)
   
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User not found')

        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User account is not active.')

        return user 


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email', 'username')
```

```
# account/views.py

'''from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect , get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy

from account.forms import *
from jobapp.permission import user_is_employee 


def get_success_url(request):

    """
    Handle Success Url After LogIN

    """
    if 'next' in request.GET and request.GET['next'] != '':
        return request.GET['next']
    else:
        return reverse('jobapp:home')



def employee_registration(request):

    """
    Handle Employee Registration

    """
    form = EmployeeRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
        return redirect('account:login')
    context={
        
            'form':form
        }

    return render(request,'account/employee-registration.html',context)


def employer_registration(request):

    """
    Handle Employee Registration 

    """

    form = EmployerRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
        return redirect('account:login')
    context={
        
            'form':form
        }

    return render(request,'account/employer-registration.html',context)


@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:login'))
@user_is_employee
def employee_edit_profile(request, id=id):

    """
    Handle Employee Profile Update Functionality

    """

    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    form = EmployeeProfileEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Your Profile Was Successfully Updated!')
        return redirect(reverse("account:edit-profile", kwargs={
                                    'id': form.id
                                    }))
    context={
        
            'form':form
        }

    return render(request,'account/employee-edit-profile.html',context)



def user_logIn(request):

    """
    Provides users to logIn

    """

    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                auth.login(request, form.get_user())
                return HttpResponseRedirect(get_success_url(request))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request,'account/login.html',context)


def user_logOut(request):
    """
    Provide the ability to logout
    """
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'You are Successfully logged out')
    return redirect('account:login')

    '''

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, login, logout
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import UserRegisterSerializer, UserLoginSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions, status
from .validations import custom_validation, validate_email, validate_password


class UserRegister(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):
        clean_data = custom_validation(request.data)
        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=clean_data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.create(clean_data)
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserLogin(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    ##
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        assert validate_email(data)
        assert validate_password(data)
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.check_user(data)
            login(request, user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class UserLogout(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = ()
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


class UserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    ##
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response({'user': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Regards.

I set `auth_user_model = 'account.AppUser'`.

I did makemigrations,migrate. I actually copied `AppUser()`, `CustomerUserManager()` which was in managers.py into models.py as I do not them in separate file.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you are using the "AbstractBaseUser" then you can use the authentication method provided by django for the user model, and there is no need for the "check_user" in the UserLoginSerializer, so for me, the code will be like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class UserLogin(APIView):

    def post(self,request):
                
            serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                email = serializer.validated_data['email']
                password = serializer.validated_data['password']
                
                user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
                if user:
                    return Response({"Message":"Succecssful login"})
                else:
                    return Response({"Message":"Email or password is not correct"})
```

And for the Serializer i think it's ok although i think that using Modelserializer will be better.